# Djoser UserViewSet, getting 401 Unauthorized `as_view("get": "list")`

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, djoser

When I utilize POSTMAN to test the endpoint, I encounter a 401 Unauthorized error. I would greatly appreciate your assistance in comprehending the nature of the issue that has caused this unauthorized access error to occur.

{
"detail": "Authentication credentials were not provided."
}

**accounts.views.py**

```
 from djoser.views import UserViewSet
    from .serializers import UserCreateSerializer
    from .models import AddressDetails, UserProfile
    from rest_framework import status
    from rest_framework.response import Response

     # Create your views here.
     class UserCreateView(UserViewSet):
     serializer_class = UserCreateSerializer

     def create(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        # Extract user account data from the request
        user_data = {
            "email": request.data.get("email"),
            "user_role": request.data.get("user_role"),
            "password": request.data.get("password"),
        }

        # Create a user account
        user_serializer = UserCreateSerializer(data=user_data)
        if user_serializer.is_valid():
            user = user_serializer.save()
        else:
            return Response(user_serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)

        # Extract and create AddressDetails data
        address_data = {
            "address_line_one": request.data.get("address_line_one"),
            "address_line_two": request.data.get("address_line_two"),
            "address_line_three": request.data.get("address_line_three"),
            "province": request.data.get("province"),
            "barangay": request.data.get("barangay"),
            "city": request.data.get("city"),
            "zip_code": request.data.get("zip_code"),
        }
        AddressDetails.objects.create(**address_data)

        # Extract and create UserProfile data
        profile_data = {
            "user": user,
            "first_name": request.data.get("first_name"),
            "middle_name": request.data.get("middle_name"),
            "last_name": request.data.get("last_name"),
            "date_of_birth": request.data.get("date_of_birth"),
            "gender": request.data.get("gender"),
            "relationship_status": request.data.get("relationship_status"),
            "phone_number": request.data.get("phone_number"),
            "address_details": address_data, 
        }
        UserProfile.objects.create(**profile_data)

        return Response(data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
```

**config.urls.py**

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include, re_path
from accounts.views import UserCreateView

# drf yasg
from rest_framework import permissions
from drf_yasg.views import get_schema_view
from drf_yasg import openapi

schema_view = get_schema_view(
    openapi.Info(
        title="Djoser API",
        default_version="v1",
        description="REST implementation of Django authentication system. djoser library provides a set of Django Rest Framework views to handle basic actions such as registration, login, logout, password reset and account activation. It works with custom user model.",
        contact=openapi.Contact(email="contact@snippets.local"),
        license=openapi.License(name="BSD License"),
    ),
    public=True,
    permission_classes=(permissions.AllowAny,),
)

urlpatterns = [
    path("api/v1/users/", UserCreateView.as_view({"get": "list"}), name="user-create"),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    re_path(r"^api/v1/docs/$",
    schema_view.with_ui("swagger", cache_timeout=0),
    name="schema-swagger-ui",
    ),
    path("api/v1/", include("accounts.urls")),
    path("api/v1/", include("djoser.urls")),
    path("api/v1/", include("djoser.urls.authtoken")),
]
```

**accounts.serializers.py**

```
   from djoser.serializers import UserCreateSerializer
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
from rest_framework import serializers
from phonenumber_field.modelfields import PhoneNumberField #type: ignore

User = get_user_model()

class UserCreateSerializer(UserCreateSerializer):
    first_name = serializers.CharField(max_length=150,)
    middle_name = serializers.CharField(max_length=150,)
    last_name = serializers.CharField(max_length=150,)
    date_of_birth = serializers.DateField()
    gender = serializers.CharField(max_length=1,)
    relationship_status = serializers.CharField(max_length=150,)
    phone_number = serializers.CharField(max_length=150,)

    address_line_one = serializers.CharField(max_length=150,)
    address_line_two = serializers.CharField(max_length=150,)
    address_line_three = serializers.CharField(max_length=150,)
    province = serializers.CharField(max_length=150,)
    barangay = serializers.CharField(max_length=150,)
    city = serializers.CharField(max_length=150,)
    zip_code = serializers.CharField(max_length=150,)

    class Meta(UserCreateSerializer.Meta):
        model = User
        fields = (
            "id",
            "email",
            "user_role",
            "password",
            "first_name",
            "middle_name",
            "last_name",
            "date_of_birth",
            "gender",
            "relationship_status",
            "phone_number",
            "address_line_one",
            "address_line_two",
            "address_line_three",
            "province",
            "barangay",
            "city",
            "zip_code"
        )
```

**config.settings.py**

```
"""
Django settings for config project.

Generated by 'django-admin startproject' using Django 4.2.

For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/topics/settings/

For the full list of settings and their values, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/settings/
"""

from pathlib import Path

# Build paths inside the project like this: BASE_DIR / 'subdir'.
BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = 'django-insecure-a+!z_4han7cjf)#3n1qf*7tn_&bc79p**abob#sa7_m_5kj3@e'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []


# Application definition

DJANGO_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
]

PROJECT_APPS = [
    "accounts",
]

THIRD_PARTY_APPS = [
    'rest_framework',
    'rest_framework.authtoken',
    'drf_yasg',
    'djoser',
    'phonenumber_field',
    'corsheaders',
]

INSTALLED_APPS = DJANGO_APPS + PROJECT_APPS + THIRD_PARTY_APPS

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware', # middleware for cors-headers
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'config.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'config.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'NAME': 'db_healthwatch',
        'USER': 'root',
        'PASSWORD': 'password1',
        'HOST': 'localhost',
        'PORT': '3306',
    }
}


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = 'static/'

# Default primary key field type
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/settings/#default-auto-field

DEFAULT_AUTO_FIELD = 'django.db.models.BigAutoField'

# Django Custom User Model
AUTH_USER_MODEL = "accounts.UserAccount"

# django-phonenumber-field configuration
PHONENUMBER_DB_FORMAT = "NATIONAL"
PHONENUMBER_DEFAULT_REGION = "PH"

# authentication scheme configuration
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    "DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES": ["rest_framework.permissions.IsAuthenticated"],
    "DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES": (
        "rest_framework.authentication.TokenAuthentication",
    ),
}

# djoser configuration
DJOSER = {
    "USER_CREATE_PASSWORD_RETYPE": True,
    "USERNAME_CHANGED_EMAIL_CONFIRMATION": True,
    "PASSWORD_CHANGED_EMAIL_CONFIRMATION": True,
    "SEND_CONFIRMATION_EMAIL": True,
    "SET_USERNAME_RETYPE": True,
    "SET_PASSWORD_RETYPE": True,
    "PASSWORD_RESET_CONFIRM_URL": "password/reset/confirm/{uid}/{token}",
    "USERNAME_RESET_CONFIRM_URL": "email/reset/confirm/{uid}/{token}",
    "ACTIVATION_URL": "activate/{uid}/{token}",
    "SEND_ACTIVATION_EMAIL": True,
    "SERIALIZERS": {
        "user_create": "accounts.serializers.UserCreateSerializer", # custom serializer
        "user": "djoser.serializers.UserSerializer",
        "current_user": "djoser.serializers.UserSerializer",
        "user_delete": "djoser.serializers.UserSerializer",
    },
}

# cors headers configuration
CORS_ORIGIN_ALLOW_ALL = True
CORS_ALLOW_CREDENTIALS = True

# email configuration
EMAIL_BACKEND = "django.core.mail.backends.console.EmailBackend"
EMAIL_HOST = "localhost"
EMAIL_PORT = "1025"
EMAIL_HOST_USER = ""
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = ""
EMAIL_USE_TLS = False
```

Comment: It seems your endpoint is encountering an authentication issue. Make sure to include the necessary tokens or credentials in POSTMAN requests. Review your Django project's authentication settings, and if possible, share your REST_FRAMEWORK settings for a more accurate diagnosis. Providing this information will enable me to offer targeted suggestions to address the issue.